# Iterating over data from a retrieved file to extract various values

Tags: python, regex

I'm searching through a text file (example file shown below) and I'm trying to select various data from each group.  For example I want to select "random text-x" data from each group, the "findMe" text, and the numbers from each group (e.g. from group A "100-012" and "499-217"), although the count of numbers in each group is unknown.

```
EXAMPLEFILE.TXT:
 1. [**] random text group A [**]
 2. random number of lines of text 
 3. findMe
 4. stufff...100-012 qwerty...499-217


 5. [**] random text group B [**]
 6. random lines of text 
 7. findMe


 8. [**] random text group C [**]
 9. random number of lines of text 
10. findMe
11. stufff...223-300 qwerty...888-888 zzzz...333-444

12. [**] continues......
```

My code is shown at the end, but it only outputs:

`random text-A 
findMe
['100-012', '499-217', '223-300', '888-888', '333-444']`

I'm really struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```
import re

def patternMatching(group, line):
    section = re.findall(group, line)     
    for i in section:
        randText = re.search('\]\s(.*?)\[', i)
        result1 = randText.group(1)
        print result1
        findMe = re.search('findMe', line)
        result2 = findMe.group()
        print result2
        numbers = re.findall('(\d{3}\-\d{3})',line)
        print numbers

randomTextgroup = re.compile(r'\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\]', re.DOTALL|re.S)
with open ("C:/Location/test.txt", 'r') as txt:
    data=txt.read().replace('\n','\r')
    a = randomTextgroup.findall(data)
    for i in a:
        patternMatching(randomTextgroup, i)
```

The output I was aiming to get was:

```
random text group A
findMe
100-012 499-217

random text group B
findMe

random text group C
fineMe
223-300 888-888 333-444
```

For the group of numbers, I didn't really mind if it came in as ['223-300', '888-888', '333-444'], or as a tuple - just as long it was grouped so I could work with it.

Comment: Can you include an expected output? (in the form of actual code, e.g. should your output be `[{"Text Group A": ["100-012", "499-217"]}, ...]` or etc) and also what makes all these things special. How do we know if it's a `findMe` that we should capture or a `qwerty` that we shouldn't?

Comment: (Expected output included with original post) With the actual data I'm working with there are characters I can ofset the "findMe"s to; e.g each findMe may be preceded by a <  (I tried to make my example clear, but I see something like that could be better off included) Thanks for the edit, that formatting had me stumped.

Comment: What is this used for `\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\]` ? Where it should probably be this `\*{2}\].*\[\*{2}\].*(?=\[\*{2}\])`

Comment: Indeed you're right I should have excluded the last [**] from being retrieved, thanks (I wasn't aware of that until now :)  My idea was to read in each group so then I could perform other regex searches on those groups.

Comment: @Soap thanks for the edit! Can you give us one chunk of your actual input? No need to list the whole file, we should be able to extrapolate from just one. I'm a bit confused about your assertion that `each findMe may be preceded by a <` does that mean that ALL findMes will be? How do we tell? Are they always on the second to last line? With regex it's usually easier to think in terms of ruling out everything that's NOT supposed to be captured rather than trying to capture everything that should be captured (which ultimately is just `(.*)` :D)

Comment: A sample of the actual input is here <http://pastebin.com/mbyFUtQ4>.  I was looking to extract the same type of data from each alert e.g. the IP address and Port, the alert heading/signature, etc.  Then from the URL's I was looking to extract the cve numbers e.g. 2002-0013 and 2002-0012.  N.B. As seen on pastebin some alerts may have the cve details (the actual number of them is unknown) while others will not.

Thanks for the tip on capturing :) There's a problem with the link..2 minutes....

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. That regex should be non-greedy `\*{2}\].*?\[\*{2}\].*?(?=\[\*{2}\])`

Comment: Here's a working link http://pastebin.com/84jG0FeM .Thanks @sln, that's something I will read up on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got! :)  Thanks @AdamSmith and @sln for your help and advice.  Indeed the major factor was that the regex (@ randomTextgroup) was greedy.  Then the additional for loop in patternMatching() resulted in there being no data...one for loop too many.  Anyway, thank-you :)

```
randomTextgroup = re.compile(r'\*{2}\].*?\[\*{2}\].*?(?=\[\*{2}\])')


with open ("C:Location/test.txt", 'r') as txt:


    data=txt.read().replace('\n','\r')


    section = randomTextgroup.findall(data)


    for i in section:

        randText = re.search('\]\s(.*?)\[', i)
        test = randText.group(1)
        print test

        findMe = re.search('findMe', i)
        result2 = findMe.group()
        print result2

        numbers = re.findall('(\d{3}\-\d{3})', i)
        print numbers, '\n'
```

This results in the output below:

```
random text-A 
findMe
['100-012', '499-217'] 

random text-B 
findMe
[] 

random text-C 
findMe
['223-300', '888-888', '333-444']
```

N.B. for other readers the input file remains the same (as written in the original post)